# Turned sink / faucet water off via angle stop. Now won't turn back on

Tags: plumbing

my faucet was leaking so I decided to turn of the water to replace a stem. it is a price pfister. I turned the angle stops to the "off" position. Now I have turned them back to the "on" position, but almost no water comes out. Basically just a tiny drip comes out. What happened and can I fix it?

Edit: TO add more info I checked the aerator and that is not the problem

edit 2: There is a sprayer extension which also has no water pressue...so I am guessing the issue is a clog or something right near the angle stop? any thought on what to do?

edit 3: okay I switched out the new stem for the old one. I also noticed the gasket on the old one was shaped slightly differently than the new one. Eventually I was able to get the water back on, but then I turned off one of the angle stops and now the water pressure is gone again. Any thoughts?

Comment: to add more information I checked the aerator and that is not the problem

Comment: When you mention angels stops are you meaning ball valves? A valve that only turns 90 degrees from on to off.?